# Shrinkable disk images in QEMU?

Tags: android, qemu

I've [read](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/images.html) about growable disk formats in QEMU. In my use case i'm going to use growable `qcow2` format (because it supports snapshots mostly) on mobile device where the storage is very limited. My mobile app users can install some applications in QEMU VM "just to see" and then uninstall. So it will probably grow disk size but it will not be effectively used later.

Is there any "auto shrinkable" disk format (at all and supported by QEMU in particular)? If there is nothing out-of-box, how can i shrink it programmatically (note QEMU admin utils are missing on mobile device)? Any related QEMU monitor commands available? Any tricks (like convert from qcow2 to qcow2 having side effect of shrinking to the actually used size)/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

virt-sparsify tool is your friend in this case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Shivaprasad bhar "...note QEMU admin utils are missing on mobile device.."